# Reactjs conditional rendering still flashes nested Component for a second

Tags: javascript, reactjs, modal-dialog, conditional-statements, rendering

I am showing in first render an initial Adblock notification Modal, when adblock is on..
the problem is, for a second or so, there is a flashing of my App Component behind the modal to see.. although I made the rendering of the App COmponent conditionally...
Here is my starting point index.js:

```
import './index.css'
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';
import App from './App'
import { AuthProvider } from './providers/AuthProvider'
import AdBlockComponent from './components/AdBlockComponent'

const container = document.getElementById('root')
const root = createRoot(container);

root.render(
    <AdBlockComponent>
        <AuthProvider>
            <App />
        </AuthProvider>
    </AdBlockComponent>
)
```

My AdblockComponent:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { useDetectAdBlock } from 'adblock-detect-react'
import Modal from './Modal'
function AdBlockComponent({ children }) {
    const adBlockDetected = useDetectAdBlock()
    const [isAdBlockerOn, setIsAdBlockerOn] = useState(false)

    useEffect(() => {
        if (adBlockDetected) {
            setIsAdBlockerOn(true)
        } else {
            setIsAdBlockerOn(false)
        }
    }, [adBlockDetected])

    const noticeContentJSX = () => {
        return (
            <div className="mx-auto">
                <div className="mx-auto text-center space-y-4">
                    <h2 className="text-xl font-semibold">Disclaimer</h2>
                    <p>
                        SOME UNIMPORTANT TEXT
                    </p>
                    <div className="flex justify-around">
                        <button
                            className="bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded-full mt-5"
                            onClick={() => window.location.reload()}>
                            Refresh
                        </button>
                        <p className=" py-2 px-4  mt-5">or</p>
                        <button
                            className="bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded-full mt-5"
                            onClick={() => setIsAdBlockerOn(false)}>
                            Just continue
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>


            </div>
        )
    }
    return (
        <>
            {isAdBlockerOn ? (
                <Modal show={true}>{noticeContentJSX()}</Modal>
            ) : (
                children
            )}
        </>
    )
}

export default AdBlockComponent
```

my modal.jsx:

```
import React from 'react'
import classes from './Modal.module.css'

const modal = props => {

    return (
            <div
                className={classes.Modal}
                style={{
                    transform: props.show
                        ? 'translateY(0)'
                        : 'translateY(-100vh)',
                    opacity: props.show ? '1' : '0',
                }}>
                {props.children}
            </div>
    )
}

export default React.memo(modal)
```

finally, my App.jsx:

```
import { React, useEffect } from 'react'
import { useTitle } from './components/utils'

import { useLanguage } from './customHooks/useLanguage'
// import TagManager from 'react-gtm-module'
import { IntlProvider } from 'react-intl'
import { Provider as StoreProvider } from 'react-redux'
import { getAnalytics, logEvent } from "firebase/analytics";

import store from './store'
import RouterComponent from './components/RouterComponent'


    function App({title}) {
        useTitle(title)
        const [locale, changeLocale, translations] = useLanguage();
    
    
        return (
                <StoreProvider store={store}>
                    <IntlProvider locale={locale} messages={translations[locale]}>
                        <RouterComponent />
                    </IntlProvider>
                </StoreProvider>
        )
    }
    
    export default App
```

How can I avoid the initial rendering of my App Component (although condition is false), so that the screen does not flash initially?
I already thought to pass the condition down to my app and then make rendering condition there in my app, but not sure if that would change anything, because I don't understand how that rendering happens initially anyway..

Comment: The `useLayoutEffect` function is triggered synchronously before the DOM mutations are painted. However, the `useEffect` function is called after the DOM mutations are painted. maybe this would help?

Comment: Perhaps you could do the checking and calling of the modal further down the tree, say at the component level, and trigger the opening of the modal from there. But maybe this way is also less elegant than wrapping the whole app as you currently do...

Comment: @OmarDieh I added `useLayoutEffect(() => {
        if (adBlockDetected) {
            setRenderSubcomponent(children)
        } else {
            setRenderSubcomponent(null)
            setIsAdBlockerOn(false)
        }
    }, [adBlockDetected, children])`
then rendered the subComponent, it did not make any difference.. no idea why